# object are not valid as Reactchild in react-jsx-parser

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to render my HTML string containing this `{{some_toekn}}`,but I am getting this error

> object are not valid as react child

Comment: The only object that you are allowed to render directly in JSX is array.

Comment: I don't want to render this as object. actually I want to parser my string which is like 
"<string>{{my_token}}</strong>"

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue then I replace my package with *html-react-parser* like:

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
parse(my string)
```